# How to scale the android emulator in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I know how to do this in Eclipse, but can't seem to find a setting like the one in Eclipse in Android studio.

I'm running Android Studio V0.8.14

Comment: You can always launch your emulator from the AVD Manager, and scale it that way.

Comment: This works, thanks man. That's a good workaround, though it isn't exactly an answer to my question. Thanks again. :)

Comment: This is the same question of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737499/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-android-studio) and the answer there is perfect!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

In Android Studio(version 1.0.2) go to `Run->Edit Configurations...`, you may add `-scale 0.x` (replace `x` with the scale, example `-scale 0.75`) like in the image above, adjust it so that it fits your needs. Apply and your set. this can be set for separate images.