# Android Emulator Exceeds screen size

Tags: android

**Android emulator not working properly.**
Emulator size exceeds screen(desktop) size and when I run the app it shows

> "Failed to install d.apk on device 'emulator-5554!" 
>   "launch failed."

Desktop resolution is 1366x768 and AVD config is for device with resolution 480x800

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Did you try creating a new emulator with different size?

Comment: Check my answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737499/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-on-android-studio/29739254#29739254

Comment: @RajSharma  Yes,i tried creating emulators with different sizes.@nKaushik Changing Scale didn't solve the problem.But thanks for the help. Appreciate It.