# Creating android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to android, when I click run button to create AVD it appears as follows, I can't understand what it says, please help me to understand  what it means and how can I fix this

> C:\Users\neil\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\tools\emulator.exe -avd
>   Nexus_S_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none Creating filesystem with
>   parameters: could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>       Size: 69206016
>       Block size: 4096
>       Blocks per group: 32768
>       Inodes per group: 4224
>       Inode size: 256
>       Journal blocks: 1024
>       Label: 
>       Blocks: 16896
>       Block groups: 1
>       Reserved block group size: 7 Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize
>   OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it. could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>   could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>   could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES
>   1.x config! Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string! Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

Comment: under your create/edit emulator setting uncheck Use Host GPU option.

Comment: Thanks, It works, but it appears in a separate window, I cant at least resize it,what the wrong with it, can you help me please

Comment: please accept as answer if it works. As for resizing the emulator  is not possible unless you are using the Emulator that was released recently (2.0 Preview). Resize functionality was introduced in this. You can look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29739254/2745762

Answer (score 0):

Under your create/edit emulator setting *uncheck* **Use Host GPU option**

To resize using a command is possible but not using visual controls.
Note: However in the last update to the Emulator this functionality has been introduced.