# How to resize the AVD emulator to the given device screen size?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have defined some custom devices with rather unusual screen sizes and resolutions (I use the term *screen size* for the length of the display diagonal, and the term *screen resolution* for the number of pixels).
I hoped that the *auto scale* device parameter will show the emulator screen in the size as defined in the custom device settings. It does not.
I am aware of `window scale` command and have calculated the specific scale factor based on the MacBook Pro retina density of 220ppi and my custom device screen density, but still get the wrong size.

I could use a physical ruler and resize the emulator window till the screen size is correct, but reject to believe that there is no better way.

[Here](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/08/how-to-resize-the-android-emulator/) is what I would expect to be possible with the AVD too.

Anybody had to deal with this before and know how to instruct the emulator to resize the window so that the screen size is as defined for the custom device?

---

**UPDATE:**

As described at the end of [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html): *"When you launch an AVD from the AVD Manager, you can specify the screen size for the emulator and your monitor dpi in the Launch Options, as shown in figure 7."*

The problem is that it seems to be broken, as it only takes care of the device screen resolution and the display density.

Comment: have a look here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737499/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-android-studio

Comment: @Tasos as described in my question, I do know how to resize the AVD emulator ... I would like to resize it so that it is exactly 5.6" on my MacBook Pro if the custom device is configured to have the diagonal of 5.6"