# Android studio emulator displaying screen wrongly

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to use the emulator in android studio, but the screen is displaying with the wrong size and even position. This is what it looks like.

[image]

I've tried changing android device, android operating system, and turning off the border, none of which solved my problems. I'd appreciate help. I'm afraid this problem is causing by DPI aware scaling - I have a high resolution screen.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38406614/2949612
It may helps you.

Comment: I also tried different setitngs with no success. PC reboot helps however.

Comment: @AlexeyOzerov I have the same problem, yet restarting didn't help. Was there anything else you did?

Answer (score -1):

It's a nice aesthetic touch to see it as an "actual" device, but if it's not going to display properly, it's just an eyesore. Disabling the frame also seems to make the emulator run smoother as well.

In Android Studio 3.14

1. Tools -> AVD Manager
2. Actions -> Edit this AVD (Pencil icon)
3. Uncheck Enable Device Frame

Comment: its not working...