# Not able to set virtual machines launched in AVD manager to full screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, fullscreen, android-virtual-device

A lot of older posts about AVD manager and its Android emulators suggest that device screen can be set to full screen by using Alt+Enter. In my case - it does not work. Neither does F11 or other shortcut key do the trick. To sum up what I want to know is, does the AVD manager emulators even support such thing? If yes, how, if not - are there any workarounds for it. The target device is a touchscreen monitor, so running in full screen is most important. Bonus question - is it possible display the toolbar with control icons (for controlling rotation, volume, hardware keys etc.) separately from main window in case the device screen is in fullscreen mode?

Comment: if you haven't seen it yet, this SO post *might* be useful. it seems to have a lot of different answers and approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737499/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-android-studio

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is not quite what I want. The scaling works with dragging the corner, but what I want to achieve is complete full screen. I know Genymotion allows that, but, as I said, I want AVDs to be able to do the same.

Comment: Yes, it's true, I've seen a lot of old posts mentioning alt enter as a solution, but I guess this no longer works, I only managed to full screen by using Vmware Player with Android Image. Another desperate solution is to use a software that resizes the window, like Borderless Gaming (for Windows)
Check here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrM_tNXX3uI

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

1. Install BorderlessGaming Software

   - (https://www.techspot.com/downloads/7061-borderless-gaming.html)

   > With de Emulator running, use it to force fullscreen on it (set as automatic).

   > Set BorderlessGaming to Run on Windows Start
2. Commandline to run Emulator

   > Here is a simple Script to load the Android VM:

```
@echo off

REM Setting the name of the virtual machine
set AVD_NAME=Pixel_2_API_33

echo Starting the Android emulator...
REM Command to start the emulator
echo Starting the emulator...
start "" /MAX cmd /c "cd /d %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\emulator && emulator.exe -avd %AVD_NAME% -scale 0.25"

echo Android emulator started successfully.
echo Closing the script in 5 seconds...
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul
exit
```

Now, with this BorderlessGaming Started, everytime you load the Emulator, it will force it to fullscreen.