# Android emulator is not showing the phone screen in full size

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to android, when I launch my first app, it is not occupying the entire screen size of the emulator (attached the screenshot).
Any reason why it is showing up like this.[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435272/android-emulator-screen-fills-up-only-some-fraction-part-of-actual-android-emula

Answer (score -1):

android default emulator is really slow and useless
use leapdroid instead,it's really powerful and fast
[download leapdroid from here](https://leapdroid.en.softonic.com/)