# Android Emulator not rendering correctly

Tags: android, android-emulator

A friend of mine (who doesn't have enough reputation to post images) is facing a problem with his emulator. It is not rendering as it should, even though the clicks are where they should be. In order to click on the Back button, he must click down in the black part of the "screen".

[image: The problem described above]

He already tried to restart his computer, change monitor resolutions and creating another emulator images.

He uses KDE and is using his NVidia hardware to process graphics.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435272/android-emulator-screen-fills-up-only-some-fraction-part-of-actual-android-emula

Comment: Wow, didn't find that. Tried those answers with him and nothing could solve the problem =/

Answer (score 0):

My answer from this post: [Android emulator screen fills up only some fraction part of actual android emulator screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45435272/1353170)

---

Best and simplest way to do it on Windows 10:

1. Close your Android Emulator if it is open
2. Right-click desktop
3. Click `Display` Settings
4. Set Scale and layout to 100%
5. Open Android Emulator
6. Revert your `Scale and layout` to the `(Recommended)` percentage

Answer (score 0):

**WORKS 100%**

You can fix the scaling issue when using the Hardware rendering by simply making windows override the scaling setting. How?, it's very easy. Simply locate the .exe file for the emulator that you are using, (e.g. "qemu-system-armel.exe" for ARM and "qemu-system-x86_64.exe" for x86). To make sure which .exe file, just run the emulator then use task manager to locate the .exe file is running, see the screenshot. locate the .exe file using task manager

In my case it was in this location: **"C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"**

[image: Screen shot of the .exe file task manager]

Now just right click on the file then click on properties then choose the "Compatibility" tab. Under "Settings" at the bottom, click on "Change high DPI settings". A new window will open. Tick the last checkbox "Override high DPI scaling behavior." under "High DPI scaling override". Then select from the drop down below it "System" (this is very important or it will not make any difference!), see the screenshot below. Now just hit OK and OK. Restart Android Studio and that's it, problem solved :)

[image: And the result!!]