# Android Studio emulator display issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm starting a course at college that REQUIRES me to use Android Studio 3.3 RC3 version. I have downloaded it and Android 6.0 (Marshmallow).

I am having issues with the rendering of the image on the emulator. When I first started I used a frame and it was fine. Went on to my next class and had to install Git. Tried the emulator again and for some unknown reason I get the view shown below.[Screenshot of Emulator display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlw0y.png)

I have been on the reddit page r/AndroidStudio and basically followed all reasonable suggestions (removing the frame was one). Nothing works.

Also tried uninstalling AS and removing all files (yes I know there are more that you have to remove after the uninstall has finished - although I may have missed some?) and reinstalling it.
[Uninstall directions that I followed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjjri.png)

I've tried used different emulators and every one of them has the same issue … it puts it in the top left corner of the emulator and I can only use the sidebar menu items.

I have an ASUS Zenbook UX430UAR Signature Edition; Windows 10 Home Version 1709; 
Intel® Core ™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz to max 1.99GHz; 16 GB RAM; 512 GB Storage; PCIe Solid State Drives (SSD); no separate Graphics card.

I don't believe it's the type of laptop rather it must be a setting that was either changed by me or when I installed GIT.

I'm desperate to fix this as I need it to work to be able to continue my course. Any help is greatly appreciated and let me know if I need to add any extra information.

Comment: this post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435272/android-emulator-screen-fills-up-only-some-fraction-part-of-actual-android-emula

Comment: Awesome!  It worked :-)  Thank you so much!!