# Android emulator showing only small part of screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have already deleted and reinstalled but I still get the same problem. If someone knows how to fix, please answer.

Thanks.

[image: AVD showing Small portion of screen]

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435272/android-emulator-screen-fills-up-only-some-fraction-part-of-actual-android-emula

Comment: I already try it but I got bad resolution.

Comment: It's strange!!!