# Android Studio Emulator not working properly:shows giant emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

[so this is what happens if I run an application no errors but a giant emulator which I cant control with mouse only takes keyboard input and the scene inside the emulator quite smaller than the emulator][1]

when I first installed android studio it was working right.Please help me if you know anything about I tried to reinstall it didnt work.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8BcB.png
It also says Launching 'app' on No Devices. when I run

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `AVD Manager`.

Edit the AVD. (Pencil Icon)

In the "Emulated Performance" select the "Software" option.

[image]

**EDIT**

Open AVD Manager and click the drop down menu (upside down triangle) and click wipe data for your AVD. This can resolve 'Launch on no device error'.

Comment: it didnt work. It Also says Launching 'app' on No Devices.

Comment: So if you open the emulator from AVD manager without running your application does it display properly?

Comment: Unfortunately no it doesnt

Comment: Sir launch on no device error couldnt solved by wiping data

Comment: Try the solutions from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435272/android-emulator-screen-fills-up-only-some-fraction-part-of-actual-android-emula