# Android emulator appearing as a small box in the top left corner of the window

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-emulator

[Android emulator Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypmX0.jpg)

Hello, i have used this fantastic website many times over the years to find answers others have already provided. This problem i have not been able to find an answer to anywhere. As the title describes, every time i create a new Android Virtual Device using Android Emulator 2.0 within Android Studio 2.3.3 it displays the screen in the top left corner of the window. I have no idea why this is happening, i have tried uninstalling and re-installing HAXM. I have tried creating multiple different devices with different specifications and i always get the same problem. Does anyone know how i can get the screen into the correct position and the correct size? I'm operating on Windows 10 Cheers,
James

Comment: At least edit your question with what PC/OS version are you using, version of Android Studio, SDK and which AVD are you building. Also how does XAMPP relate to your question.

Comment: Its a samsung s7 edge black AVD. Edited**

Comment: You might want to add in which version of Windows 10 along with what graphics hardware you have - CPU/GPU, number of monitors. I would also try building a non-HAXM AVD just to see if anything different happens (other than being slow). Also may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737499/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-android-studio

Answer (score 6):

Solved, The external graphics(NVIDIA GTX1050) card in my device was interfering with Android Virtual Device.

Fix - When creating a new Android Virtual Device in the Verify Configuration window set Emulated Performance - Graphics: to Software - GLES 2.0
[image: image explanation]