# How to scale to 1:1 the AVD emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to resize the screen of the emulator in **Android Studio 3.1.4** to match the real size of the emulated device.

In previous version of Android, you could set it in the [Run Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29739254/9625828) or in the [AVD Device Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32028096/9625828), but it's no longer the case.

According to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39894182/9625828), you can manage the size by pressing Ctrl + UP or Ctrl + DOWN, but I want to compare my app between two devices with different sizes, that's why I need **scale 1:1**.

According to the above answer, you can also modify files in this directory:

> C:\Users\YOUR
>   USERNAME.android\avd\Nexus_XX_API_XX.avd\hardware-qemu.ini

But there is no field for the scale or the width and height of the emulator (only the real width and height of the emulated device).

Does anyone know how to scale to 1:1 the emulator in Android Studio?
**Is that even possible ?**

Comment: Hm, -scale command line parameter is deprecated now - https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#deprecated

Comment: Ugh on MacOs there seems to be no way to reset it anymore...