# Show emulator window in smaller size

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Each time I start Android emulator in Android Studio emulator takes whole monitor. Can I somehow ask Android Studio scale emulator window by 50%?

How to achieve that?

Comment: You can resize emulator just by dragging on corner when resize arrow appears

Comment: I need it to start in right size without dragging

Comment: Then select smaller resolution display in emulator

Comment: your question already exists check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737499/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-window-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the emulator size just by moving your mouse cursor into an emulator corner and pressing the left mouse button two times and holding the button and a resize icon will appear and then resize according to your required size[screen shot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cozuE.jpg).